# Run VBScript on server from javascript/php

Tags: php, javascript, com, vbscript

I have a Single Page Application written in JavaScript and PHP, I am trying to run an external .vbs file on my server?

I have tried using the php COM class as well as exec() to no avail. Has anyone successfully achieved this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this gem: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156587.aspx

By that, you should try the similar in PHP:

```
exec('wscript "C:/path/to/script.vbs"');
```

Comment: May I note that it DOES NOT have to be the whole path, path can be relative :-)

Comment: I wanted to write `C:/` to indicate that this only works on Windows, but you should have known that already. :)