# Running a .vbs script via HTML/javascript/php on Cognos Report Studio

Tags: javascript, php, html, cognos

I am trying to run a .vbs script on server side via code (HTML Item) on Cognos Report Studio.
I have already tried using `<a href="..\samples\scripts\script.vbs"> button </a>` but it just opens the script text on browser.

I have tried this code below using PHP, but it did not work:

```
<?php
    function runScript(){
        exec("samples\scripts\script.vbs");
        echo("done");
    }
?>

<a href=# onclick="runScript();">
```

How could I do that?

EDIT: Both client and server are Windows machines.

Comment: Maybe duplicate : [Run VBScript on server from javascript/php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410163/run-vbscript-on-server-from-javascript-php)

Comment: I have tried the solution using 'wscript "../samples/scripts/script.vbs"' but it did not work too

Comment: Are you working on Unix or Windows ?

Comment: Windows, client and server are Windows

Answer (score 0):

I think you do it the wrong way. Create 2 files :

I assume you activated `COM` class.

Page launcher.php :

```
<a href="executeVbScript.php">Execute VB</a>
```

Page executeVbScript.php

```
exec('wscript "C:/samples/scripts/script.vbs"');
```

Start with `launcher.php` page.

Comment: Thank you. I know I can create the executeVbScript.php on server, but I don't know if Cognos' HTML items are saved as .php files or .HTML files. I'll try it and if it works I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: You mean the script must be run on client ?

Comment: No, the vbs must be run on server. I just don't know yet if Cognos' HTML items accept php commands. When I ran it the commands did not show up at the page, so I think it accepts.